# How can a read csv.deflate hdfs files in a dask datfarame?

Tags: csv, hdfs, dask, deflate

I am trying to read csv.deflate files from hdfs path and put them in dask dataframe. I tried read_csv and I am getting "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 1: invalid start byte" error. Then,  I set engine='python' and encoding='utf-8' but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the compression= keyword would help?  How would you read this data locally with Pandas?  I suspect that you need the same keyword arguments that you would need in that case.